# Unretweet all the tweets using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

The following code will un-retweet a single tweet by id:

```
# calling the api  
api = tweepy.API(auth) 
  
# the ID of the tweet to be un-retweeted 
ID = 
  
# un-retweeting the tweet 
api.unretweet(ID)
```

I want to know how to un-retweet **all the tweets** that ever been retweeted?

Comment: You can use [list_timeline](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=retweets#API.list_timeline) or [home_timeline](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=retweets#API.home_timeline). You need to filter the Status object that they were made by you and is a retweet. Then you can extract the id from the Status object and unretweet. Note that the Twitter API has limitation on how far you can go back using the API.

Comment: can you explain this in code?